# Converter Date Kotlin

Tags: api, data, kotlin

Seguinte,recebo uma data json de uma api:

```
"data": "2021-05-03T14:07:19.000Z"
```

preciso convertela para mostrar ao usuario...
fiz meu data class com ela: `Data : Date`

no Adapter chamei ela com uma função que volta para o data class assim:

```
fun Date.formatte(): String =
    android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy - HH:mm ", Locale("pt-br", "America/Sao_Paulo"))
        .format(this)
```

em fim ela retorna,a hora e data correto porem com 3 Horas a menos...o que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Olá Gabriel, 
Acho que a data que vem no JSON está sem o GMT, e você está aplicando o GMT na sua conversão. Por isso a diferença de horas.

Comment: Opa ainda não deu certo!